# Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь запустить следующий скрипт:

```
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


class SearchByJobTitle(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://hrm.seleniumminutes.com"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_search_for_qa_manager(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        self.assertEqual("OrangeHRM", driver.title)
        driver.find_element_by_id("txtUsername").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("txtUsername").send_keys("123")
        driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword").send_keys("1234")
        driver.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()
        self.assertEqual("OrangeHRM", driver.title)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#menu_pim_viewPimModule > b").click()
        Select(driver.find_element_by_id("empsearch_job_title")).select_by_visible_text(
            "QA Manager")
        driver.find_element_by_id("searchBtn").click()
        self.assertEqual("OrangeHRM", driver.title)

        # OPTION #1
        # retrieve 5th cell from all rows in the table
        all_results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr/td[5]")

        # loop through each resulting element
        for single_result in all_results:
            # check the text of each 5th cell to ensure in contains QA Manager
            self.assertEqual("QA Manager", single_result.text)

        # OPTION #2
        # retrieve all rows in the table
        all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr")

        # loop through each resulting row
        for row in all_rows:
            # check the text of each 5th cell to ensure in contains QA Manager
            self.assertEqual("QA Manager", row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[5]').text)

        driver.find_element_by_id("welcome").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Logout").click()
        self.assertEqual("OrangeHRM", driver.title)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Пытаюсь выполнить скрипт в PyCharm, Selenium и Python установил. В коде, насколько я вижу, все верно. Не могу понять как решить проблему, уже часа 2 пробую разные версии Python и Selenium ставить, ошибка одна и та же, хотя на другом компе (Windows) запускается без проблем. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Запустить пытаюсь на маке.

Вот такая ошибка вылазит:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.060s
FAILED (errors=1)

 Error
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 322, in run
self.setUp()
 File "/Users/myname/Desktop/HRM2017/HW5_SearchByJobTitle.py", line 10, in setUp
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
self.service.start()
     File "/Users/mynane/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
  WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 



   Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Comment: Если коротко - нужно установить geckodriver и прописать его в переменную окружения PATH.

Answer (score 1):

1 Вам надо скачать `geckodriver`. Его можо взять [здесь](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

2 
a) Можно просто путь до geckodriver прописать в PATH.

b) Или же можно сделать так:

```
self.driver= webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='your\path\to\geckodriver')
```